# Negation of a Statement with Quantifiers -- If Then?

Tags: quantifiers

I need to find the negation of a statement on my homework, specifically problem 19 of secton 3.2 in *Discrete Mathematics with Applications* by Susanna Epp. The problem is as follows:

> \begin{align} \neg\left(\forall n\in \mathbb{Z},\:n\:\text{is
> > prime}\:\longrightarrow\:n\:\text{is odd or}\: n=2.\right)\tag{1}
>  \end{align}

In this case, do I have to negate the if-then, or is it simply as I have written it already in which I have negated either side:
\begin{align}
\Longleftrightarrow \exists n\in\mathbb{Z},\:n\:\text{is not prime}\longrightarrow\:n\:\text{is not or}\:n\neq 2.\tag{2}
\end{align}
My gut is telling me that I have it wrong, which is why I would appreciate a second opinion. Once again, I realize that it is not your job to do my homework. Tips and hints to get better along the way would be much appreciated, however.

Comment: This question is not really about mathematical logic, so I have removed the 'logic' tag (see its tag description)

Comment: @CarlMummert My apologies. I suppose I may have mistakenly added it given that just earlier at this time I was working on logic problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $(2)$ is wrong. Consider the simpler case :

$$
\neg(\forall n\in\mathbb Z)(P(n)\to D(n)).
$$

Since $P(n)\to D(n)$ is equivalent to $\neg P(n)\vee D(n)$ we get :

$$
\begin{align}
\neg(\forall n\in\mathbb Z)(P(n)\to D(n))&\iff\neg(\forall n\in\mathbb Z)(\neg P(n)\vee D(n))\\
&\iff(\exists n\in\mathbb Z)\neg(\neg P(n)\vee D(n)).
\end{align}
$$

Can you proceed from there?

Comment: in the last line you want $(\exists n \in Z) \cdots$

Comment: @abel Actually I wanted to write $\neg(\forall n\in\mathbb Z)\ldots$, but for some reason I didn't write the $\neg$. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Workaholic, I went and looked in another textbook for an identity that would help and I found the same: $$P\longrightarrow Q \Longleftrightarrow \neg\left(P\vee Q\right).$$ Thanks for answering!

Comment: @bd1251252 No it's $\;P\to Q \iff \neg P \vee Q\;$ only the antecedant ($P$) is negated, not the whole disjunction.  This leads to another the identity, how to negate an implication: $\; \neg(P\to Q) \iff P\wedge \neg Q\;$.

Comment: My bad, I wrote it wrong (careless mistake). If I could edit my comment I would